# How to disable Aero Peek during Alt+Tab?

Tags: windows-7, aero-peek

Aero Peek is a nice feature generally but I find it very annoying during Alt+Tabbing (peek windows hiding the switch dialog, it doesn't really work on multiple monitors etc.). Is there a way to disable Aero Peek **only** during the Alt+Tab operation? I don't want to turn it off globally.